# how to display text in a table dynamically?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

i m using asp.net..In login form i m using requiredfield validator and regularexpression validator for username.so i need to display the error message in same td for both validation.that first it need to validate required field and display the error msg in td.if that is field it need to checkfor that expression and overite the error message in same td..

This my html.on button click validations are working but error message are displaying in consecuent position..

```
       <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="l_uname" runat="server" CssClass="label" Text="User Name" ></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="t_uname" runat="server" CssClass="text" ToolTip="Enter Username"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>           
        <td>
        <label class="l" runat="server">*</label>
        </td>
        <td>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rf_uname" CssClass="t" runat="server"           ErrorMessage="Enter the username" 
          ControlToValidate="t_uname"    ValidationGroup="logingroup"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
         <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="Re_name" runat="server"
            CssClass="t"  ControlToValidate="t_name" ValidationGroup="logingroup" 
            ValidationExpression="^[A-Za-z ]{6,20}$" ErrorMessage="Name should be 6-20 character">
            </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <asp:Button ID="login" runat="server" Text="Login" ValidationGroup="logingroup"     onclick="login_Click"/>
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add display dynamic (Display="Dynamic") to both the validator control they won't be displaying in consecuent position..

Like this

```
 <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rf_uname" CssClass="t" runat="server"           ErrorMessage="Enter the username" 
              ControlToValidate="t_uname" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="logingroup"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
             <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="Re_name" Display="Dynamic" runat="server"
                CssClass="t"  ControlToValidate="t_name" ValidationGroup="logingroup" 
                ValidationExpression="^[A-Za-z ]{6,20}$" ErrorMessage="Name should be 6-20 character">
                </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

if you have a td with css class "tdclass" then use text() method

```
$('.tdclass').text("message");
```

if you want to write Html then use **html()** method

Comment: on button click the validation will be performed.then how can i able to set this.it needs to be vary based on the two validation..sorry if i wrongly understood what u told..can u tell me detail.

Comment: you want to do this server side or client side?

Answer (score 0):

Both validators will run together. To run them out at a time, you will need to `Enable` the second validator at server side. Not a very good approach.

A better approach would be to have only one Regex validator with a proper message to indicate that it is required and between 6-20 characters

```
 <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="Re_name" runat="server"
        CssClass="t"  ControlToValidate="t_name" ValidationGroup="logingroup" 
        ValidationExpression="^[A-Za-z ]{6,20}$" 
        ErrorMessage="Username is required to be between 6-20 characters">
        </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

For clientside validation, take a look at the [jQuery Validation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) plugin. It is simple, all you need to do is add css classes to tell it what validation to apply. It does support more complex rules where needed.

Comment: thanks..but it wont work if they click the button without entering anything in textbox.Also i need to perform some more validation for the same textbox.In register page there are many textbox for each i need to do many validation all need to be in a client side..So is there any way to do by using javascript or somehow?

Comment: take a look at the jQuery Validation plugin. Updated my answer